# robotino-ros-pkg installation

Tags: ros, robotino, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to Ros and Ubuntu, I am working on Festo Robotinos and I need to perform [Mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/robotino_navigation/Tutorials/Mapping%20with%20Robotino) with them. For this purpose I have installed the [Nootrix Ros Indigo Pre Installed Virtual Machine](http://nootrix.com/software/ros-indigo-virtual-machine/). (To verify the correctness of ROS, I created and successfully ran a Hello World program)

I then downloaded code from [this SVN repository](http://svn.openrobotino.org/robotino-ros-pkg/).
To build the checked out code completely, do I need to create separate catkin packages and manually copy paste and build? or is there a simpler more intelligent way to build the whole package in it's entirety.

When I tried to `catkin_make` the checked out code, it says please build from the root folder Please let me know if more details are required.Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234756/robotino-ros-pkg-installation/) by [Karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/26928/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2016-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Typically, you have your catkin pacakges in a `src` folder, in another folder. Let's call this folder `catkin_ws`.
`catkin_ws` then is your root folder, so you need to call `catkin_make` therein.

Make sure, you have called `catkin_init_workspace` in your  `src` folder before.

---

**EDIT**

`catkin_make` provides out-of-source builds. So there will not be any executables in `src`, but in `devel`.
Also, checking the link you provided, I'd say that you only need to put `trunk/catkin_pkg` stuff in there. The rest is based on the legacy `rosbuild` build tool and will thus not be built with `catkin_make`.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/26928/karthik/) on 2016-05-20**:
Hello, Thanks for the reply. I get what you are saying but there are no catkin_ws from the default svn architecture. I wanted to know if I needed to create a separate catkin_ws for every folder, there are 8 folders that I need to build that is why I wanted a more experienced opinion before I started

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-20**:
No, one folder into where you put all the source packages that you want to compile.
Ideally, you just checkout the respective repository (being it svn, git or whatever) into the `src` folder...

**Comment by [Karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/26928/karthik/) on 2016-05-20**:
I created a package (called catkin_WS) inside which i created src and then placed the placed the contents of robotino-ros-pkg/trunk/robotino.Upon doing catkin_make, it got compiled (created a build folder but no devel). But once I go inside the src, there are no exes generated in any folders

**Comment by [Karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/26928/karthik/) on 2016-05-26**:
Thanks mig for the answer..It worked!